# Is there a conceptual derivation of the formula for the composition of two EGFs?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Exponential generating functions (EGFs) can be used to represent different classes of connected undirected graphs.  Composition of EGFs has the following interpretation.

> If $F(x)$ represents graphs of type I and $G(x)$ represents graphs of type II, then $F(G(x))$ represents the graphs that can be constructed by first constructing a graph of type I and then replacing each of its vertices with a graph of type II.

It is straightforward to prove this in terms of a formula.  Let $F(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{f_n}{n!} x^n$ and $G(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{g_n}{n!} x^n$.  Then

$$F(G(x)) = \sum_{n \geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\sum_{k \leq n} \frac{f_k}{k!} \sum_{\begin{matrix}n_1, \ldots, n_k \,\geq\, 1\\n_1 + \cdots + n_k \,=\, n\end{matrix}} \binom{n}{n_1, \ldots, n_k} g_{n_1} \cdots g_{n_k}\right) x^n \tag{1}\label{a}$$

Moreover, after studying the formula for a moment, one observes that it expresses the interpretation of $F(G(x))$ mentioned above.

Is there is there a conceptual proof that does this in reverse?  That is, can we prove that $F(G(x))$ has the boxed interpretation above without deriving the formula first algebraically?  If so, then the formula \ref{a} for $F(G(x))$ would be immediate and hopefully such an argument would also provide some intuition into *why* the composition of two EGFs has such a nice interpretation.

---

Here is a straightforward but unenlightening derivation of the formula for \ref{a}.  We start by considering two ordinary generating functions (OGFs) $A(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n$ and $B(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} b_n x^n$.  Then

$$(B(x))^k = \sum_{n \geq k} \sum_{\begin{matrix}n_1, \ldots, n_k \,\geq\, 1\\n_1 + \cdots + n_k \,=\, n\end{matrix}} b_{n_1} \cdots b_{n_k} x^n$$

Therefore,

\begin{align}
A(B(x)) & = \sum_{k \geq 0} a_k \sum_{n \geq k} \sum_{\begin{matrix}n_1, \ldots, n_k \,\geq\, 1\\n_1 + \cdots + n_k \,=\, n\end{matrix}} b_{n_1} \cdots b_{n_k} x^n \\
{} & = \sum_{k, n \geq 0} \;\; [n \geq k] \; a_k \sum_{\begin{matrix}n_1, \ldots, n_k \,\geq\, 1\\n_1 + \cdots + n_k \,=\, n\end{matrix}} b_{n_1} \cdots b_{n_k} x^n \\
{} & = \sum_{n \geq 0}\left(\sum_{k \leq n} a_k \sum_{\begin{matrix}n_1, \ldots, n_k \,\geq\, 1\\n_1 + \cdots + n_k \,=\, n\end{matrix}} b_{n_1} \cdots b_{n_k} \right) x^n \label{b} \tag{2}
\end{align}

Now, consider the EGFs $F(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{f_n}{n!} x^n$ and $G(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{g_n}{n!} x^n$.  Then by applying \ref{b}, we see that

\begin{align}
F(G(x)) & = \sum_{n \geq 0}\left(\sum_{k \leq n} \frac{f_k}{k!} \sum_{\begin{matrix}n_1, \ldots, n_k \,\geq\, 1\\n_1 + \cdots + n_k \,=\, n\end{matrix}} \frac{g_{n_1}}{n_1!} \cdots \frac{g_{n_k}}{n_k!}\right) x^n\\
{} & = \sum_{n \geq 0}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\sum_{k \leq n} \frac{f_k}{k!} \sum_{\begin{matrix}n_1, \ldots, n_k \,\geq\, 1\\n_1 + \cdots + n_k \,=\, n\end{matrix}} \binom{n}{n_1, \ldots, n_k} g_{n_1} \cdots g_{n_k}\right) x^n
\end{align}

which is precisely the formula \ref{a}.